# What does if (print) means in Perl?

Tags: perl

I got the following code

```
if (print msgsnd($ipc_msg_to_mppt_id, $msg, 0)) {
```

what is the purpose of `print` here? What is returns?

Documentation says it returns `true` if successful. But how can printing be unsuccessfull?

Comment: Since msgsnd() is a perl built-in IPC function which returns true or false, I suspect the print() there may be a coding error. You'd have to look at the wider code context to be sure though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printing isn't necessary as simple as dumping the output to a console. It could also be redirected to a file or some other kind of pipe. If it's redirected to a file you don't have write access to, then printing to that file will fail. If it's piped into another program and the latter program terminates, then writing to it will cause a broken pipe error.

As a general principle, I/O operations are outside the control of your program, so you should always assume that they can fail. Reading to or writing from a file, the console, or any kind of socket or pipe, can always, without warning, fail. So if you want your program to do something about it, you'll need to check the return value of functions like `print`.

Comment: While everything you said is true, the real answer here is that the `print` probably should be there at all.

Comment: Additional info about `print`: Returns true on success. Returns false on and sets `$!` on error. Note that success doesn't mean that the data was actually sent to the OS. It could be in a buffer. To see if all data has been sent to the OS, make sure to check if `close` succeeds.

Comment: @ikegami "shoult" or "shouldn't"?

Comment: @Dims, ack, *shouldn't*.